# TO navigate to other page when clicked on callout

Tags: iphone

I folks,

I have a requirement that user can click on any location and there it should display a callout and when we clicked that callout it should navigate to other page.
If ur selects some location say Delhi or some other streets there it should display a callout in the select region and when clikced on this callout it should navigate me to other page.

Comment: Try to explain question properly.then you may get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

IF You want callout click , please use UIButton in Call Out (rightCalloutAccessoryView)

use this code in MkMApViewDelegete

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(Annotation *) annotation {

    if(annotation == map.userLocation) return nil;

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";


    MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                           initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(showDetails)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

   
    return customPinView;


}


-(void)showDetails
{
//  go to detail page code ...use pushController
}
```

if you have any problem
please [download](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html) this code (by apple)

Comment: it is not working...please send me total code as i am new to iphone i cant get this.

Comment: how to tap the location that means user should click on any loaction there it should display the pin.. is this possible in iphone